# Google cloudshell method for moving a large number of files based on file number range?

Tags: json, google-cloud-storage, move, gsutil

I backed up a Big Query table to JSON files in a Google cloud bucket.  There are approx 90k JSON files, totalling 19TiB.

I want to restore this backup back to a Big Query table.  However, the BQ Load command has a maximum 15TiB limit so I am trying to divide the backup files into 2 buckets and do 2 BQ Load jobs, one BQ Load job on each bucket.

How would I copy approx half the 90k JSON files over to a new bucket?

The filenames look like this:

```
gs://mybackupbucket/table-000000000000.json 
...
gs://mybackupbucket/table-000000000038.json
gs://mybackupbucket/table-000000000039.json
gs://mybackupbucket/table-000000000040.json
...
gs://mybackupbucket/table-000000088921.json
```

I tried:

```
gsutil -m mv gs://mybackupbucket/table-0000000{00001-45000}.json gs://mybackupbucket2/
```

But that didn't work.

I also tried:

```
gsutil -m mv gs://mybackupbucket/*[00000-45000].json gs://mybackupbucket2/
```

That seemed to copy every file with a 0-5 at the end. So, files ending in 0-5, 10-15, 20-25, 30-35 etc.

How can I move files numbered 0-45000?

I have managed to divide the files in a hacky way (*[7000].json seemed to copy numbers ending in 7, which made both buckets under the 15TiB limit) but it would be great to just say copy the first 45000 files.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your files that contain a numeric name based on the number range that you want using the `bash` approach:

```
gsutil -m mv gs://bucketname/table-*{0..45000}*.json gs://bucketname2
```

Comment: I tried it on a subset of the first 26 files.  

`gsutil -m mv gs://some-bucket-4-testing/2/table-*{0..15}.json gs://some-bucket-4-testing/1/`. 

copies all of the files in the bucket across instead of the first 15.  

writing it like this solved it:  

`gsutil mv gs://some-bucket-4-testing/2/table-0000000000{01..24}.json gs://some-bucket-4-testing/1/`. 

This copied every file in the range 01-24, leaving 25-26.  It needed every file in the range 01-24 in the bucket otherwise it would error out.

Comment: I will need to run 5 gsutil commands to copy the 1st 45000 files:

`gsutil -m mv gs://some-bucket-4-testing/2/table-0000000{10000..45000}.json gs://some-bucket-4-testing/1/`
`gsutil -m mv gs://some-bucket-4-testing/2/table-00000000{1000..9999}.json gs://some-bucket-4-testing/1/`
`gsutil -m mv gs://some-bucket-4-testing/2/table-000000000{100..999}.json gs://some-bucket-4-testing/1/`
`gsutil -m mv gs://some-bucket-4-testing/2/table-0000000000{10..99}.json gs://some-bucket-4-testing/1/`
`gsutil -m mv gs://some-bucket-4-testing/2/table-00000000000{0..9}.json gs://some-bucket-4-testing/1/`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gave me something to go on.

Comment: You are correct it needs the filename is in the range. If you want something to handle this, I suggest to create a bash script. I believe just using `gsutil` can't handle this scenario.